# What happens when I vote my own post for closing?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, flags

There is a **flag** button for voting to close a post. I can do that on my own post also.

What will happen when I vote my own question to close?

Comment: Is there possibility of losing points?

Comment: It is exactly as having your question closed by 5 users other than yourself. As long as the question is not deleted, you won't lose the reputation you might have gained.

Comment: Is the accepted answer (still) correct? I thought my question got insta-closed the last time I did this. (I don't have any gold tag badges).  Also, considering the accepted answer, shouldn't this be tagged [support], not [discussion]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vote to close on your own question counts as a regular vote to close. It is not a binding vote, but will simply be mixed into the other votes to close, 5 of which are needed to close a question.